# Н.В. Гоголь.

Tags: литература

В каком произведении Гоголя отразился его духовный кризис середины 50-х годов XIX века? Есть варианты: "Мертвые души", "Вечера на хуторе близ Диканьки", "Петербургские повести", "Выбранные места из переписки с друзьями". Вот я отметила "Мертвые души" — оказывается, неправильно!

Answer (score 1):

"Выбранные места из переписки с друзьями" однозначно. Непонятно только, как может идти речь о середине 50-х годов, если Гоголь умер в 1852?

Answer (score 0):

петербурские повести - шинель (образ маленького человека), нос (сатира).